# GetStream get activities is getting them all instead of specific ID

Tags: ios, swift, stream, getstream-io

I'm working on a function that connects to GetStream in order to get the activities for a chosen feed group. The problem is that GetStream is returning all the activities inside the feed group as opposed to the ones for a specific slug. In MySQL terms it's ignoring the WHERE UUID = uuid :)

Here's the code I'm currently using which returns all activities, I've tried setting the elementFeed to nil before setting it but that doesn't work either.

```
    func getStream(uuid: String, completion: @escaping([StreamActivity], Bool, APPError?) -> Void) {

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()

    var activities     = [StreamActivity]()
    elementFeed = nil
    elementFeed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "element", userId: uuid)

    elementFeed?.get(typeOf: StreamActivity.self, enrich: false, pagination: .limit(20), ranking: "", includeReactions: [], completion: { results in
        if let foundActivities = results.value?.results {
            activities.append(contentsOf: foundActivities)
            group.leave()
        } else {
            completion([], false, .GetDiscussions)
            group.leave()
        }
    })

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.isUserFollowing(uuid: uuid) { (following) in
            completion(activities, following, nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the code used to create the activity:

```
func addActivity(type: ActivityType, body: String?, uuid: String, completion: @escaping(Bool, APPError?) -> Void) {

    var feed: FeedId?
    var originFeed: FeedId?

    switch type {
    case .comment:
        feed = FeedId(feedSlug: "element", userId: uuid)
    case .reply:
        originFeed = FeedId(feedSlug: "comment", userId: uuid)
    default:
        break
    }
    let activity = StreamActivity(actor: StreamUser.current!, verb: type.rawValue, object: "element:\(uuid)", body: body!)

    activity.feedIds = [feed!]


    elementFeed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "element", userId: uuid)

    elementFeed?.add(activity, completion: { (result) in
        if result.error == nil {
            completion(true, nil)
        } else {
            completion(false, .PostComment)
        }
        print("GETSTREAM: Activity added:\(result)")
    })
}
```

Comment: that's not possible; you cannot read from more than one feed at the time. the code you shared reads activities from one element feed (element:$uuid). If you include the logic used to add activities and perhaps some more info on what is wrong with the integration that will help a lot

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli - Added in the add activity code

Answer (score 0):

Stream Feed API does not allow you to read activities outside a feed. Feeds are materialised so when you perform a call like this

```
Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "element", userId: uuid)
```

You are not performing a query (ie. SELECT * FROM activities WHERE slug = ? AND userId = ?) but you are reading the activities that were added (directly, via to targets or from followed feeds) to the element:$uuid feed.

If a feed contains wrong activities it is because something is going wrong with the logic used to add activities or to create follow relationships.

When you read a feed, Stream adds information about the origin of each activity; such information is stored in a field called "origin". If the origin field is missing / null it means the activity was added to the feed directly; if the activity was added via follow relationship, then the origin field will be set to the feed id from where the activity originated.

For example:

If element:x follows user:z; all activities user Z adds are propagated to element:x and will have origin = "user:z" on that feed.

You can use the origin field to get some more information about why the activity is in a feed; that should be very useful information to find out where the integration problem is.